# JavaFX Slider Tick Marks Initialized via CSS Disappear

Tags: java, css, javafx, slider

I am using CSS to configure my JavaFX Sliders, then applying the style in code with:

`cssSlider.getStyleClass().add("slider-style");`

When I first open my window, the tick marks are present on the CSS configured Slider(s).  When I close and reopen the window, the tick marks are no longer present.

This following example demonstrates the anomaly using 2 Sliders, one configured directly, the other via CSS.  Click the button to hide the window for 2 seconds.  Notice that the Slider in which I directly configure the attributes works fine after hiding and re-showing, but the CSS configured Slider loses its tick marks after hiding and re-showing.

Does anyone have any ideas why showing, hiding, and re-showing the window causes the tick marks to vanish from the CSS configured Slider?  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a JavaFX bug?

sample.css:

```
    .slider-style {
        -fx-show-tick-marks: true;
        -fx-snap-to-ticks: true;
        -fx-major-tick-unit: 5;
        -fx-minor-tick-count: 5;
    }
```

CssExample.java:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    
    /**
     * This simple example demonstrates that JavaFX Sliders configured with CSS only show their tick marks the first time
     * they are shown.  If the Slider is hidden, then shown again, the tick marks are gone forever.
     */
    public class CssExample extends Application {
     
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Slider Sample");
            scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            grid.setVgap(10);
            grid.setHgap(70);
    
            scene.setRoot(grid);
            int rowNumber = 1;
    
            Label directLabel = new Label("Slider from attribute assignment");
            GridPane.setConstraints(directLabel, 1, rowNumber++);
            grid.getChildren().add(directLabel);
    
            Slider directSlider = new Slider();
            GridPane.setConstraints(directSlider, 1, rowNumber++);
            grid.getChildren().add(directSlider);
            directSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
            directSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
            directSlider.setMajorTickUnit(5);
            directSlider.setMinorTickCount(5);
    
            Label cssLabel = new Label("Slider from CSS (tick marks disappear after hidden)");
            GridPane.setConstraints(cssLabel, 1, rowNumber++);
            grid.getChildren().add(cssLabel);
    
            Slider cssSlider = new Slider();
            GridPane.setConstraints(cssSlider, 1, rowNumber++);
            grid.getChildren().add(cssSlider);
            URL url = getClass().getResource("sample.css");
            String cssString = url.toExternalForm();
            scene.getStylesheets().add(cssString);
            cssSlider.getStyleClass().add("slider-style");
    
            Button button = new Button("Hide for 2 Seconds");
            GridPane.setConstraints(button, 1, rowNumber++);
            grid.getChildren().add(button);
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    stage.hide();
                    stage.show();
                }
            });
    
            stage.show();
        }
     
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't sleep the JavaFX thread for any reason.

Comment: That is not what I am doing in my real code.  We actually close the window, while holding onto it in another window and reopen it.  I needed a minimal solution to display here.  The sleep() has nothing to do with the functionality breaking, as it does the same thing in our "held" window that is closed and reopened (without a sleep).  To demonstrate, I just deleted the entire try/catch (including the sleep) and the anomaly remains.

Comment: Please delete it from the question too, then, as it’s an immediate distraction for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

> is this a JavaFX bug?

Yes.

See: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/SliderSkin.java#L398

It is a bug in the internal implementation of the `setShowTickMarks` method of `SliderSkin` (verified in JavaFX 18.0.1).

Test case:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CssExample extends Application {

    private static final String CSS = // language=CSS
            """
            .slider-style {
                -fx-show-tick-marks: true;
                -fx-snap-to-ticks: true;
                -fx-major-tick-unit: 5;
                -fx-minor-tick-count: 5;
            }      
            """;

    private static final String CSS_INLINE = "data:text/css," + CSS;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        Slider cssSlider = new Slider();
        cssSlider.showTickMarksProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                System.out.println(cssSlider.showTickMarksProperty())
        );
        cssSlider.getStyleClass().add("slider-style");

        PauseTransition hideAnimation = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        hideAnimation.setOnFinished(e -> stage.show());

        Button hideWindow = new Button("Hide for 2 Seconds");
        hideWindow.setOnAction(e -> {
            stage.hide();
            hideAnimation.play();
        });

        Button closeApp = new Button("Close app");
        closeApp.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                cssSlider, hideWindow, closeApp
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefSize(400, 120);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS_INLINE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
BooleanProperty [bean: Slider@132908b9[styleClass=slider slider-style], name: showTickMarks, value: true]
BooleanProperty [bean: Slider@132908b9[styleClass=slider slider-style], name: showTickMarks, value: false]
BooleanProperty [bean: Slider@132908b9[styleClass=slider slider-style], name: showTickMarks, value: true]
```

It switches showTicks from true to false, and back to true, which triggers the bug.

In the current implementation for the setShowTicks method:

```
private void setShowTickMarks(boolean ticksVisible, boolean labelsVisible) {
    showTickMarks = (ticksVisible || labelsVisible);
    Slider slider = getSkinnable();
    if (showTickMarks) {
        if (tickLine == null) {
            tickLine = new NumberAxis();
            tickLine.setAutoRanging(false);
            tickLine.setSide(slider.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL ? Side.RIGHT : (slider.getOrientation() == null) ? Side.RIGHT: Side.BOTTOM);
            tickLine.setUpperBound(slider.getMax());
            tickLine.setLowerBound(slider.getMin());
            tickLine.setTickUnit(slider.getMajorTickUnit());
            tickLine.setTickMarkVisible(ticksVisible);
            tickLine.setTickLabelsVisible(labelsVisible);
            tickLine.setMinorTickVisible(ticksVisible);
            // add 1 to the slider minor tick count since the axis draws one
            // less minor ticks than the number given.
            tickLine.setMinorTickCount(Math.max(slider.getMinorTickCount(),0) + 1);
            if (slider.getLabelFormatter() != null) {
                tickLine.setTickLabelFormatter(stringConverterWrapper);
            }
            getChildren().clear();
            getChildren().addAll(tickLine, track, thumb);
        } else {
            tickLine.setTickLabelsVisible(labelsVisible);
            tickLine.setTickMarkVisible(ticksVisible);
            tickLine.setMinorTickVisible(ticksVisible);
        }
    }
    else  {
        getChildren().clear();
        getChildren().addAll(track, thumb);
//            tickLine = null;
    }

    getSkinnable().requestLayout();
}
```

The first time it shows the ticks it will do this:

```
getChildren().clear();
getChildren().addAll(tickLine, track, thumb);
```

Then, when the ticks are hidden, it will do this:

```
getChildren().clear();
getChildren().addAll(track, thumb);
```

Then, when the ticks are supposed to be shown again, the `tickLine` is not added back to the children, so it never shows the ticks again.